# Substring with Index - PostgresQL - Efficient way

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I creating a trigger in postgres for the purpose of auditing. When we insert/update the table. Using the audit 91 trigger I am able to successfully log user and his actions.

Using the `current_query()` function I get the text of query that recently executes. I need to create a new column of `created_by` AND `update_by` in the audit table after extracting values from below string. How to go about it ?

Like in java we do as

String.Substring(string1.indexOf("updated_by"), string1.indexOf("updated_by") + 10)

or similar to extract "Roxan" and then I can save it to another column.

updated_on => "2023-03-15 23:37:57.120968", created_on => "2023-03-15 23:37:57.120968", id => 100, updated_by => Roxan, id_2 => 400000, id_3 => 800001,node_id => 131, created_by => Jason, tok_id => -764590865

[image]

Highly appreciate guidance on how to go about it

Comment: Please don't tag spam. You're clearly not using both Oracle and PostgreSQL simultaneously, as they are totally different RDBMSs from different companies, with different syntax and functionality. Using tags that do not apply to your post is a quick way to collect downvotes and get your post closed. Please [edit] to remove the tags that do not apply to your post.

Comment: Done, Removed Oracle and Kept only postgresQL

Comment: Any pointers would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: The place to start with any problem is with your favorite search engine - I'm just using the basic SO search functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BPostgreSQL%5D+substring should give you a place to start.

Comment: Are you serious about the ancient Postgres version 9.1? What is *"the audit 91 trigger"*? You wouldn't normally *"create a new column of created_by AND update_by"* in the trigger. I suspect sloppy phraseology. Please be clear about your objective.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551